# Loopback app connect to mysql google cloud

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, loopback

I am trying to deploy a Loopback app to a Flexible engine in Google Cloud connecting it to a MySQL database that it is in a Google CloudSQL instance, but I can't. When I try to deploy the app I always get the same error:

```
Web server listening at: http://localhost:8080
Connection fails: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND /cloudsql/miampa-1be3e:us-central1:miampa-prueba2 /cloudsql/miampa-1be3e:us-central1:miampa-prueba2:3306
It will be retried for the next request.
events.js:183
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
```

My `datasources.json` is:

```
{
   "db": {
      "name": "db",
      "connector": "memory"
   },
   "appAmpa": {
      "name": "appAmpa",
      "connector": "mysql",
      "host": "/cloudsql/miampa-1be3e:us-central1:miampa-prueba2",
      "database": "prueba",
      "user": "root",
      "password": "XXXXXX"
   }
}
```

and in the root folder of the Loopback app I have the app.yaml file:

```
[START app_yaml]
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
beta_settings:
cloud_sql_instances: miampa-1be3e:us-central1:miampa-prueba2

[END app_yaml]
```

The App Engine and the CloudSQL instance are in the same region: `us-central`

Any help would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution:

My datasources.json:

```
{
  "db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "memory"
  },
  "appAmpa": {
    "name": "appAmpa",
    "connector": "mysql",
    "socketPath": "/cloudsql/miampa-1be3e:us-central1:miampa-prueba2",       
    "database": "prueba",
    "user": "root",
    "password": "XXXXXXX"
  }
}
```

and my `app.yaml`

```
[START app_yaml]
runtime: nodejs  
env: flex  
beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: miampa-1be3e:us-central1:miampa-prueba2
[END app_yaml]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to check out the Google Cloud SQL proxy method as described in the google cloud SQL manual (https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy) . The host parameter within your datasources.json is invalid and therefore you cannot connect.

Comment: Thanks!! I have just found the solution 5 min ago, using: "socketPath": "/cloudsql/miampa-1be3e:us-central1:miampa-prueba2",